# Difficulty to understand how to support multiple screen

Tags: android, image, screen-resolution, screen-size

I have seen so many questions on `StackOverFlow` how to support multiple screens. But most of the answers provide [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html). And in the first one link I have got this. I am working with screen sizes first time so please help me.

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

And in case of `xhdpi` they suggest **320 density**. I am confused so I have following questions.

1. Like if I want to create Background image for xlarge screen then `960dp x 720dp` means I have to create image with **width 720 pixels and height 960 pixels** and **resolution 320** in portrait mode?
2. And if I want to create Background image for large screen then `640dp x 480dpp` means I have to create image with **width 480 pixels and height 640 pixels** and **resolution more than 200** in portrait mode?
3. The sizes above is for landscape mode i.e `960dp` for width and `720dp` for height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android-

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

1. So in your first question `960dp x 720dp` at `320dpi` means `1920px x 1440px` for xlarge screen in landscape mode using above formula.
2. `640dp x 480dp` at `240dpi` means `960px x 720px` for large screen in landscape mode.

[To learn more about check this.](https://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android)

Answer (score 4):

From Android:  [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

`px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

[image: Illustration of how Android roughly maps actual sizes and densities to generalized sizes and densities (figures are not exact)]

---

So for your example:

Your image dimensions are `960dp x 720dp` and your **dpi** is `320` (which you can see falls under XHDPI).

```
Height = 960dp * (320 / 160) = 1920px

Width = 720dp * (320 / 160) = 1440px
```

*Height and width are arbitrary depending on the orientation of the phone*

Comment: And answer of my second question?

Comment: I will let you figure it out for yourself, you have a 50% chance of getting it right your first try!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: According to your answer image dimension should be 1920px x 1440px and resolution 320 dpi? But I have so many images dont you think by this way app size increases so much?

Comment: That is the purpose of all of the different `drawable` folders in the `res` folder of your project.  For example, if you have bgpic.png, there should be `res/drawable-mdpi/bgpic.png`, `res/drawable-hdpi/bgpic.png`, `res/drawable-xhdpi/bgpic.png`, etc.  Don't make a picture for every possible `dpi`, just make a picture for each `Generalized Density` (see my picture above).

Comment: you mean image with 1920px x 1440px with resolution 320 fit properly in every screen?

Comment: It will fit well with all `xhdpi` screens, you'll need to make smaller images for the `hdpi` and `mdpi`

Comment: I am using compressed png images but still size of every image so large if i follow the rules you suggest to create images. How i decrease more size?

Comment: These comments are now outside the scope of this question, ask another question.

Comment: if you tell me its good. otherwise i will ask another question. thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this for Conversion of dp into px for each dpi (Android)
[image: Refer this for Conversion of dp into px for each dpi (Android)]

Answer (score -1):

dp means density independent pixel.
When you say for example 300dp means 300 pixels on a medium density (160dpi) screen.
So if you want to translate dp on real resolution you have to multiply the dp for the density scale factor:
es
300dp are

1. 300 px on a mdpi screen
2. 450 px on a hdpi screen
3. 600 px on a xhdpi screen

so if you specify resources you should remember to use both size and density modifiers
a background for a 480x800 px medium screen phone woul be picked from normal-hdpi folder an so on